# The Ford Emission Control System light remains steady

Tags: ford, fuel-system

I drive a 2008 Ford Escape. The Emission Control System Light turned on because I was running out of fuel. I was able to reach a gas station and put some gas but the light remains. Any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to read, then clear the codes. The code may not be what you think it is from (low fuel). If you clear it and it comes back, you know you have a larger issue. If it clears and doesn't come back, all is well in Whoseville.

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok with the car then after driving the car a full 3 warm up cycles the light should go out. If it does not then reading and clearing the code is the only option. If something is actually wrong with it, fix it.